# Raspberry Pi not loading bashrc

Tags: raspbian, script, bash, login

I recently bought and set up my Raspberry Pi 3.0 with Raspbian PIXEL. I use the default shell, bash.

Upon login, bash does not automatically execute my `~/.bashrc` script. Every other Linux distro I've run does this automatically, so I'm at loss to why Raspbian doesn't.

How can I configure my pi to load the `.bashrc` when I log in? Is there another file that bash runs on startup? If so, what is it, and what's the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Upon login, bash does not automatically execute my `~/.bashrc` script. Every other Linux distro I've run does this automatically, so I'm at loss to why Raspbian doesn't.

The first line of the default `.bashrc` should give you the answer:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
```

It's for non-login shells, you are expecting it to be loaded for the login shell. And it's the same for any bash instance, regardless of the "Linux distro".

---

> Is there another file that bash runs on startup?

Per `man bash`:

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`,  if  that  file exists.   After  reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is  readable.

---

> what's the syntax?

Either of the files mentioned above is a bash script file. No special syntax is required.

Comment: I found that after I created the file `~/.bash_profile` my `~/.bashrc` was no longer read. This is because when I SSH in, `~/.profile`, which sources `~/.bashrc`, is never read because `~/.bash_profile` exists instead. Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that has annoyed me for sometime when I ssh into a pi, and I'd have to run `bash` after successfully logging in to get a color prompt. And even then the bash configuration files I have setup in the **pi** user's **$HOME** directory are not loaded.

All that said, a cheap quick fix that I've applied on a local pi I ssh into.

Edit **/etc/bashrc** and append the below lines

```
# load user specific BASH configuration files
if [ -f $HOME/.bash_profile ]; then
  . $HOME/.bash_profile
fi
```

Then setup bash configuration settings within **$HOME/.bash_profile** to restore sanity ‍⚕️